# How to fetch data from MySQL after POST completes

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, async-await

When the user clicks a button, I want the app to

- read text from an input field
- post it to MySQL to add as a new row
- pull all rows from MySQL (including the new row)
- update the react component state with the new data it just pulled
- and rerender a list of all that data for the user

The problem I'm seeing is that pulling down all rows doesn't include the one that was just posted unless I include a manual delay (via setTimeout).

This is what my 2 functions look like

```
// gets all data, updates state, thus triggering react to rerender
  listWords() {
    setTimeout(() => fetch("http://localhost:9000/listWords")
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => this.setState({ wordList: JSON.parse(res)})), 2000)
  }


// sends new word to the MySQL database, then kicks off the listWords process to refetch all data
addWord() {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/addWord", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        word: this.state.newWord
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(this.listWords())
      
  }
```

I shouldn't have to have that setTimeout in there, but when I remove it, the listWords update doesn't have the newly posted row.

My best guess is that either

1. I'm messing up the promise `.then()` paradigm, or
2. MySQL responds to my POST request but doesn't actually add the row until the GET has already completed, thereby missing out on the new row.

**How can I ensure the POST has successfully completed before I pull the rows again?**

I am using react, express, sequelize, and for the DB it's MySQL in a docker container.

Comment: sounds like it's case 2.  do you have log on the port 9000 request handler?  check the sequence (of execution of the 2 corresponding SQL) from the log then you can verify it's case 2 or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed made a mistake, a common trap which I myself fell into as well a few times :)

When calling `addWord()` it will evaluate `then(this.listWords())`. This will immediately call `listWords()`.

Instead you pass a function to `then(...)` (instead of calling a function) for example like this:

```js
.then(() => this.listWords())
```

or even like this:

```js
.then(this.listWords)
```

Now, instead of passing the result of `listWords()` to `then()` it will pass a function that will call `listWords()` to `then()` thus only executing `listWords()` when the Promise reaches this `then()`

---

*Example to make this behavior even clearer:*

When calling a function `function foo(arg1) {}`, JS needs to know the value of `arg1` before calling `foo`. Let's take the following piece of code:

```js
foo(bar())
```

In this case, `bar()` must be called before `foo(...)` because the `arg1` will be the returned value of `bar()`. In constrast to the following case:

```js
foo(() => bar())
```

Now, `arg1` will be a function instead of the returned value of `bar()`. This is equivalent to:

```js
var arg = () => bar();
foo(arg);
```

In contrast to:

```js
var arg = bar();
foo(arg);
```

Where it is obvious what will happen.

In chained functions like `foo(arg1).bar(arg2).baz(arg3)`, all args will be evaluated before calling `foo(...)`.

---

Some help to debug such problems: Use the Network Inspector in your browser. It will show the order of requests performed and in this example you would have seen that the `GET` request was actually performed before the `POST` request. This might not explain why it happens but you can understand the problem faster.

Comment: Incredibly helpful, but still not quite working due to a new problem. The Network tab was a good reminder, the GET was happening pre-POST. So I made the arg a function, but now that never gets called. I tried putting it in `.then(() => this.listWords())` as well as `.finally(() => this.listWords())` in case it was hitting an error. But neither approach ever calls that function (shown by console logs and watching the network tab). Any ideas? I'm new to promises so I'm not surprised I'm confused.

Comment: Ok I figured out what I was doing wrong, but I don't understand. I was hitting the backend API in the call to `fetch(...)` but in the actual express route, I didn't have a `res.send(...)`. 


Why is it that lacking a `res.send(...)` in the backend express route lead to the promise not resolving (and thus not calling `.then(...)` in the front end?

Comment: @mgs I recommend adding a `.catch(e => console.log(e))` at the end of your promise chain. This way you can see why it might have stopped processing. If you see anything happening, the chain might be waiting somewhere for something to return, in this case I recommend adding logging to each step of the chain to see the issue

Comment: Also always check the browser console in such cases. Unhandled exceptions in promises *usually* get logged there

Comment: That's what I'm so confused by. It doesn't hit the `.catch()`. That simply never logs. Nor does a `.finally()`. If the express route doesn't explicitly finish with `res.send(...)` or `res.end()`, then the promise just doesn't seem to resolve. I'm sure I'll understand this one day, so no worries since it works at this point. If you are very curious, feel free to check out my (still pretty messy) code here https://github.com/grozensmith/geschichte in the routers, `client/app.js`, and `client/models/textArea.js`

Comment: @mgs Perhaps a guess: If you never send back a response, the request may simply be pending. That would mean it should time out after some time and then throw the error. Depending on the request type and browser this might take a long time. You would be able to see this in the Network Inspector. There would be a request listed that is still pending.

Comment: Wow. You are exactly right. The request is pending forever. That explains so much. If I don't have a resolution (`res.send(...)` or `res.end()`) then the promise just doesn't ever resolve because the fetch API doesn't have a timeout. Thank you so much @JensV

Comment: @mgs If I helped and answered your question could you upvote and accept the answer?